# Finding the specific outline of a set of points

Tags: c#, algorithm, geometry, computational-geometry

I have a set of "blocks" (denoted by the red and green lines) that are placed inside a "container" (denoted by the blue lines).

[image]

All of the intersection points of the blocks (green and red dots) and all relevant information of the container (angle, gradient, start,end points, etc.) are known.

I want to extract the "top-most" outline of the resultant figure after the blocks are placed (denoted by the green lines and dots).

I tried to use methods such as convex hull (shown by purple lines in the following diagram), but it does not give the exact lines.

[image]

My question is can anyone point me to a solution or some kind of algorithm that I can apply to solve these type of problems?

Comment: I came up of convex hull as well, can you explain why it does not work

Comment: Do you know what points (from the all-point list) are "green"?

Comment: @shole The convex hull will generate a purple outline as shown in the 2nd picture, whereas the output I am looking for is the green outline instead. I guess this is because the convex hull will join the boundary points directly.

Comment: @MBo No. That is what I am trying to find out. In other words, I know all the points' position (red and green), but I do not know its color.

Comment: This seems to me as computing the skyline of a point set. You can use divide and conquer or plane sweep (both n log n in 2D).

Comment: Ok I misunderstood you want to find the purple line...So for green line, I agree with @sud03r, isn't it similar to this problem: http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/divide-and-conquer-set-7-the-skyline-problem/

Comment: Yes, it is similar to the skyline problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fill the list (array ) with all points. (Repeat points in T-nodes like 2nd green point at your picture)
Sort this list by Y-coordinates
Scan list (starting from top points) like sweep line algorithm.
At every stage you'll get a pack of points with the same Y-coordinate (a pair or more).
Remove points covered be intervals  (see below) both from left and from right.
Make intervals (by X-coordinates) from pairs of these points.
Add these intervals in interval (segment) tree.
Join neighbor intervals.
Repeat until single interval cover all the top part.

Comment: Hi I couldn't quite get what you mean by removing points covered by intervals from both left and right. Could you elaborate on this?

Comment: You have not consider red points (there are green segments above them)

Comment: So the idea is as I do the sweep line, if there are points that are under the green segments, I will remove all these points?

Answer (score 0):

The convex hull should do the job.
You can check: [Fast and improved 2D Convex Hull algorithm and its implementation in O(n log h)](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1210225/Fast-and-improved-D-Convex-Hull-algorithm-and-its) for many convex hull algorithms.

As soon as it touch red points, you get before and after.